# Can I use NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes to insert multiple items in different order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'd like to insert a range of items into an `NSMutableArray` in a single operation using `insertObjects:atIndexes`, and sort the items at the same time - but I can't figure out quite how to build the correct `NSIndexSet`. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* target = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@0, @100, nil];
NSArray* itemsToInsert = @[@50, @10];

NSMutableIndexSet* indexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
// ??? what goes in indexes?

[target insertObjects:itemsToInsert atIndexes:indexes];
XCTAssertEqualObjects((@[@0, @10, @50,  @100]), target);
```

[The apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObjects%3aatIndexes%3a) doesn't really explain how it works - it implies however that the index set is going to be processed sequentially... If that's the case, then logically I should do this:

```
[indexes addIndex:1]; // insert @50 at position 1
[indexes addIndex:1]; // insert @10 at position 1, pushing @50 up to position 1
```

The problem is, this doesn't work - the insert throws an exception with `[NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes:]: count of array (2) differs from count of index set (1)`

I've also tried:

- inserting an index range - which fails with the same exception
- inserting indexes of `1, 2` - this has an incorrect result of `@[@0, @50, @10,  @100]`
- inserting indexes of `2, 1` - this *also* has an incorrect result of `@[@0, @50, @10,  @100]`

Is this possible? I could solve it by pre-sorting the list of items before I insert them, but it would be nice not to have to create a temporary copy of the list

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your specific needs, but wouldn't it be easier add the new items at the end of the array, and then sort the array using one of the sort functions?

Comment: I've got a permanently sorted array where new items are always inserted into the correct index when adding. This is much more efficient than re-sorting the entire array when you have thousands of items in it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`NSIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSIndexSet) contains only "**unique** unsigned integers", stored "as sorted ranges". What you're trying to do with the index set just won't work.

If you used an array instead to hold your indexes, you could loop through the values and indexes in parallel and use `insertObject:atIndex:` repeatedly. This would be made simpler by adding a category method to `NSMutableArray`, such as `OEInsertObjects:atOrderedIndexes:` Then your first approach, repeatedly inserting at index 1, would work, although that seems strange to me because you'd always have to take the movements into account.